# Memory usage of z3

Tags: z3

I am using z3 to solve the reachability problem of linear hybrid automata. I run the experiments under the limited memory. I am confused about the memory usage. There is a case that z3 can solve under the limited memory given bound 2500. However, the memory usage of z3 exceeds the maximal permit when the bound is set to 2000. What's the reason about this?

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the case/problem that produces this behavior? Could you provide a link to it? How did you set the bound? Are you using the API or command line tool?

Comment: The case is the reachability analysis of the temperature control system automaton. First, I encode the bounded behavior of the automata into a SMT problem, then using z3 to solve it. In fact, the number of constraints for this automata under bound 2500 is larger than that under bound 2000. I use z3 through command line: 'z3 -st tcs_2000.smt2'. The smt2 files for this automata under bound 2000 and 2500 is here:http://seg.nju.edu.cn/BACH/Demo/tcs_2000.smt2  http://seg.nju.edu.cn/BACH/Demo/tcs_2000.smt2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A smaller number of constraints in the SMT2 file does not necessarily mean that Z3 will use less memory to solve the problem. For example, a small but unsatisfiable problem may require a lot more memory than a big satisfiable problem.

It may well be that setting a lower bound on the unwinding of the automaton turns a satisfiable problem (at bound 2500) into an unsatisfiable problem (at bound 2000), which in turn makes the problem much harder for Z3, even though there are fewer constraints. Consequently, Z3 will use more time and/or memory.

Getting around this may require a different encoding of the problem or using different options on the solver, e.g., to tune the heuristics such that they get "lucky" more often and find solutions earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, this automaton is unreachable. The behavior of the automaton under bound 2500 contains that under bound 2000. For an unsatisfiable bounded model checking problem, isn't the smaller bound meaning the less solving time?

Comment: Often, but not always. This is heavily dependent on the heuristics in the solver. Could you give an indication of how big the difference is?

Comment: For example, problem A is a->b,a or b and the larger problem B is a->b,b->c,a or b or c.